# ThreadAffinity in windows

Tags: linux, windows, multithreading, porting

Currently am porting Linux application into windows, I need to set the thread affinity.

currently the Linux method is:

pthread_setaffinity_np(curthread->threadID, sizeof(cpu_set_t), &curthread->coremask);

I need to replace it with equivalent Windows call.

I have found "SetThreadAffinityMask" method as equivalent windows call. Can use this? if yes how  place the arguments to this call?

Can someone help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly useful functions:

- [SetThreadAffinityMask()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [SetProcessAffinityMask()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686223%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [GetProcessAffinityMask()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683213%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Read [Multiple Processors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684251%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [Processor Groups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd405503%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on MSDN as starter.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, thats right. But you need to do some extra work before you can call the above Microsoft API. Please refer my pseudo code explanation from the below link to achieve the same.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18499947/2724703